# get bios information using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with my powershell script.

the problem is (i think)i cant find the right class.

What i would like to acomplish today is that I can write(echo) my PSComputerName. But i keep getting the wrong info.(somethimes i dont get anything like the code below)
(important is that it has to come out of my BIOS)
my script

```
$bios = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/hp/instrumentedBIOS -Class hp_biosSetting

echo $bios.PSComputerName
```

What am i doing wrong

please help

Comment: have you tried the command: `hostname`

Comment: Do you want bios information or the hostname of the computer? win32_bios class has the BIOS information. Either of the above comments can give you the hostname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find what I was looking for.

```
$bios =Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/hp/instrumentedBIOS -Class HP_BIOSEnumeration
echo $bios.__server
```